# How push_back unique_ptr parameter onto vector of shared ptrs

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I'm having a tough time pushing back a unique_ptr from my method parameter onto a vector of shared pointers.

IFCCB.h:

```
private:
vector<shared_ptr<IFC>>  m_shpVectorIFC;
public:
void addElementVectorIFC(unique_ptr<IFC> rupIFC);
```

IFCCB.cpp:

```
void IFCCB::addElementVectorIFC(unique_ptr<IFC> rupIFC)
{
    m_shpVectorIFC.push_back(std::unique_ptr<IFC>(new IFContent(rupIFC)));
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> C2664: 'IFC::IFC(const IFC &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from
>   'std::unique_ptr>' to 'IFO *'

In this case, IFO is the heirarchical parent of IFC.  I'm not sure why it's looking at that.

I've looked at [vector info](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/pop_back/) and [shared_ptr info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279669.aspx), as well as [using unique_ptr with standard library containers](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/20/c11-using-unique_ptr-with-standard-library-containers/).

Any ideas?  I'm not used to working with shared_ptrs and unique_ptrs.

Comment: Hard to tell, but it looks to me like your error is that `IFContent` constructor doesn't accept a `unique_ptr<IFCt>`.

Comment: IFC constructor has a IFO* parameter.  But shouldn't the default constructor for IFC accept an IFC? (BTW that's a typo...IFCt is being changed to IFC above now).

Comment: Do you really want to create a new object from the `rupIFC` argument, or is that just because you couldn't get it to work? Do you just want to push `rupIFC` into the container instead?

Comment: It's the first way I thought of doing it.  I didn't think I could push_back my unique pointer onto a vector of shared_ptrs.  They need to be different...unique_ptr and vec of shared_ptrs.

Comment: But if you thought it wouldn't work why did you try to do exactly the same thing with a new `unique_ptr`?!

Comment: You are mis-understanding me.  I created a copy so I could change the type of pointer, which was what I thought I needed.

Comment: But you didn't change it ... `rupIFC` is a `unique_ptr<IFC>` and then you create another `unique_ptr<IFC>` ... that's the same type.

Comment: where?  I convert a unique ptr to shared ptr and push_back onto the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your addendum, you will need to use `unique_ptr::get()` to provide the `IFContent` constructor with the raw pointer it wants. Depending on what it does with that pointer, you may actually need to use `release` instead to prevent double-deletion. Also, no need to create an intermediate `unique_ptr` when it's just going to be converted right into a `shared_ptr` anyway:

```
void IFCCB::addElementVectorIFC(unique_ptr<IFC> rupIFC)
{
    m_shpVectorIFC.push_back(std::shared_ptr<IFC>(new IFContent(rupIFC.get())));
}
```

Comment: I don't have a getter for rupIFC.get().  I should be able to use the default constructor here, with *m_shpVectorIFC.push_back(std::shared_ptr<IFC>(new IFContent(rupIFC)))*, shouldn't I?

Comment: `rupIFC` is a `unique_ptr`, which defines `get()` to provide a raw pointer to the underlying object (I think you indicated that `IFContent`'s constructor needs a raw pointer?).

Comment: Yes, IFC's constructor needs a ptr to IFO:  IFC::IFC(IFO* pParent) :
IFO(pParent)
{

} /

Comment: It seems to be happy once I put the get() in there.  Thanks!

Comment: Just make sure ownership is clearly defined--if `IFContent` holds onto that pointer and tries to delete it later, you'll be in trouble when the original `unique_ptr` does the same thing.

Comment: `unique_ptr` is convertible to `shared_ptr` so you **can** do this

Comment: @JonathanWakely I'm surprised by that, but you're right. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: What's surprising about being able to transfer ownership from one smart pointer that to another? The conversion is perfectly safe, having the effect of releasing the object owned by the `unique_ptr` and transferring ownership to a `shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: @JonathanWakely It's surprising because, while it obviously can and does work, the act of constructing one pointer with another does not clearly (to me) indicate a *transfer* of ownership. Especially when the type of pointer being constructed is `shared_ptr`. It seems like this constructor makes it easy to make a mistake.

Comment: But the relevant `shared_ptr` takes a `unique_ptr` rvalue as its argument, which almost always means transfer of ownership ... that's pretty much the main reason `unique_ptr` exists! If an object gets constructed from a `unique_ptr` rvalue it almost always means it is taking ownership of the resources, and if the object being constructed is a `shared_ptr` then the meaning of it taking ownership from another smart pointer should be self-explanatory.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I missed that it had to be `unique_ptr&&`. I agree that in that case the transfer is unsurprising. But if there was a constructor that took `unique_ptr&`, my comments would stand. :)

Comment: Well yes, that would make it easy to make mistakes. Luckily the types are carefully designed by smart people so that isn't a problem.

Comment: Which is exactly why it surprised me when I thought you were telling me the lvalue version existed.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `push_back` takes the container's `value_type`, which is `shared_ptr<IFC>`, but you are passing it a `unique_ptr<IFC>` and the conversion from `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` uses an `explicit` constructor and can only be done from a `unique_ptr` rvalue, so the argument cannot be implicitly converted to `shared_ptr`.

To make it work you need to use `std::move` to convert the `unique_ptr` to an rvalue and then  either do the conversion to `shared_ptr` explicitly:

```
unique_ptr<IFC> p;
// ...
m_shpVectorIFC.push_back(std::shared_ptr<IFC>(std::move(p)));
```

Or use `emplace_back` instead, because that function can use `explicit` constructors to construct the new container element:

```
m_shpVectorIFC.emplace_back(std::move(p)));
```

I'm not convinced your code that creates a new `unique_ptr` is correct (why can't you just insert `rupIFC` into the container using either of the solutions shown above?) but if that's really what you want to do, the error you get is because you are trying to pass `unique_ptr<IFC>` to the `IFContent` constructor, which takes a `IFO*` not a `unique_ptr<IFC>`. To make that compile you need to get the raw pointer out of `rupIFC`:

```
std::unique_ptr<IFC>(new IFContent(rupIFC.get()))
```

However this is probably unsafe, because the pointer you passed to the `IFContent` constructor will be deleted at the end of the function when `rupIFC` is destroyed, so maybe you meant to release it:

```
std::unique_ptr<IFC>(new IFContent(rupIFC.release()))
```

N.B. as dlf's answer says, there is no point creating a `unique_ptr` if you just want to convert it to a `shared_ptr` immediately, so you could simply do:

```
m_shpVectorIFC.emplace_back(std::make_shared<IFContent>(rupIFC.release()));
```

Comment: it should be ok to create a new copy since when I do the get/pop, I'm creating a copy also.